# How to test for a break in a time series cycle

Tags: time-series, arima, change-point, frequency

I've been scratching my head over this issue and would appreciate some help. I have a time series from 1920-2011 which I've used a Baxter Kings filter on to detrend. I would like to test whether the series has fundamentally changed between periods 1950-1979 and 1980 to 2009. Spectral analysis shows periodicity is increasing in frequency, but I would like to go at this in more ways than just that. Spec analysis also says that coherence is unity at each frequency, which seems suspect to me. If anyone has any ideas, please throw them out there, I would be so appreciative!

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to this problem. Assuming you use R, have a look at [strucchange](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/index.html) for both the references and the implementation.

Comment: John, thank you for your answer. I should have been more specific, my data is actually nonlinear. Before filtering it has a hump in the middle. After filtering the frequency appears not to change, but the amplitude gets much smaller following 1980. Spec analysis says frequency has changed some, I would just like to find a test/s to see if thats true. Currently looking at the piecewise ar model, but running out of time for another cold trail. Thanks you in advance (very much) for your help!

Comment: You could consider testing for equality of the spectral coefficients at given periods (defined without looking at the data) or do the same with sliding window in which you estimate the coefficients. structchange will help you deal with the multiplicity issue arising from considering all possible windows.